# O365 Provider Hosted App: Programmatically get installed version of app in a site

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

Is there a way to check the version of Provider Hosted App installed in a web in SharePoint Online? App requires full control permission on the web and app only access is also true. So it is possible to create client context on the web using app only access and query the web/app-web properties. I can't login to the site directly so need a programmatic way using app access.

I tried client browser on my local site but don't see the app version in App Instance/App Tiles section. I need to do this as want to find the customers who are still using the older version of the App.

(in future, I can do it using app install/upgrade events but currently I don't have this data so need to get from the customer site only)

Answer (score 0):

You could check the version of app by PowerShell command.

For more detailed information, you could refer to the article below.

How to find SharePoint 2013 App Info Using PowerShell.

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/find-sharepoint-2013-app-info-using-powershell

And you also could create custom web service with SharePoint server Object Model and consume custom web service from client side.

More references:

Step by Step Procedures to create a WCF Service Application for SharePoint 2013.

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-Procedures-to-create-a-WCF-Service-Application-for-SharePoint-2013

Step by Step – Building and Consuming Custom WCF Services hosted in SharePoint.

http://nikpatel.net/2012/02/29/step-by-step-building-custom-wcf-services-hosted-in-sharepoint-part-i/

Comment: Will this work for SharePoint online?

Comment: No, the SharePoint server object model cannot work in SharePoint online. In SharePoint online, only SharePoint client object model can work.